# height property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 div tag: `<div class="right">` and `<div class="left">` both right class and left class  have height property is auto. I want `height of left = height of right`. Sorry I not enough lever to post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do `$(".left").height($(".right").height())`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get one element's height by `height()`.

and set one element's height by

`css('height', 'the height')`

so:

`$('.right').css('height', $('.left').height() + 'px');`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAkYF/1/)

**Update:**

`.height(value)`

is better :)

Comment: I think using `.css()` to set the height can be wonky unless you specify units. You should probably either use `.height(newHeight)` to set the height or append `px` to the argument of `.css()`.